# How to setState c3js graph values in react

Tags: reactjs, setstate

```
I am make a new component to call graph.
Following values I am getting from previous component:
<pre>
this.props.remaining_loan, 
this.props.total_repayment_array,
this.props.Equity_From_Appreciation_array
</pre>
Now each time I update value in previous component it is getting updated in render console but I do not know how to setState for the new values that I receive now.

My code for the graph component:
```

```
    class Graph extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          chartData: {
            columns: [
              [...['Remaining_Loan'], ...this.props.remaining_loan],
              [...['total_repayment_array'], ...this.props.total_repayment_array],
              [...['Equity_From_Appreciation_array'], ...this.props.Equity_From_Appreciation_array]
          ],
          types: {
            Remaining_Loan: 'area-spline',
            total_repayment_array: 'area-spline',
            Equity_From_Appreciation_array: 'area-spline'
              // 'line', 'spline', 'step', 'area', 'area-step' are also available to stack
          },
          groups: [['Remaining_Loan', 'total_repayment_array','Equity_From_Appreciation_array']]
          }
        };
      }



      onChange=()=>{
        this.setState({
         chartData: {columns: [
            [...['Remaining_Loan'], ...this.props.remaining_loan],
            [...['total_repayment_array'], ...this.props.total_repayment_array],
            [...['Equity_From_Appreciation_array'], ...this.props.Equity_From_Appreciation_array]
        ]
      }
        })
      }


      render() {
        console.log([...['remaining_loan'], ...this.props.remaining_loan]);
        console.log("this is the props now I found", this.props.remaining_loan);
        return (
          
            
          
        );
      }
    }
```

```
I am not getting how can I setState of this type of array.
```